# Recover lost video file/stream from an NTFS filesystem

Tags: video, ntfs, data-recovery, camstudio

I recorded an online video conference using CamStudio. Unfortunately when it reached 4 GB CamStudio suddenly warned me it couldn't save the file (because of its size or something) any more, then crashed with unhandled exception. It created the temporary file before recording and had been writing into it, but deleted it when the error occured. I tried a few data recovery software suites (GetDataBack, Restoration, Recuva, File Scavenger) to get the file back, but none of them showed me the file. Then I used google to find a solution and on a few forums they said it's unable to restore a file with this size. Unfortunately the same was proven by the applications I used.

On the flip side as well, CamStudio doesn't write an AVI header into its temporary file. So the only available information for me is that the video was encoded with the **Lossless RGBA Compression** codec, which I think is identical to **Huffyuv**. I would like to have an application which can recognize Huffyuv data patterns and extract them from stored blocks. I guess there is a distinct data pattern of Huffyuv, moreover I found a constant byte sequence with which a Huffyuv stream generally seems to start. Here you can see it in HEX and ASCII format ("00db" in ASCII):

[image]

I know the width and height of the video, also the color depth.
There must be a data recovery tool or method which could help in my situation. The question is, who knows any?

The file system is **NTFS**.

This is really urgent for me, and the recording is important. If you have any idea, please share it with me, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) by TestDisk. It can recover many different types of media files. Note that it normally recovers a very large number of files and they all appear without names which can make the results challenging to go through.

Whenever you are trying to recover data there are a few golden rules:

1. Once you become aware of a potential data loss situation, no more data should be written to the hard drive in question to minimise the chance of overwriting existing data. Additionally, operating systems often read/write data in the background, even browsing the internet requires writing to the system drive - pages that are downloaded are written into a browser cache which is stored on the hard drive.
2. Ideally the computer should be switched off and the drive connected as a secondary drive to another computer, or else rebooted from another boot device. If the drive holding your data is a secondary hard drive and not the same one upon which the data is being recovered from you might get away with installing and running your data recovery software onto the main system device. Just ensure that no other software attempts to write to the device from which you are trying to recover data.
3. Install the data recovery software onto a different media if it is not already installed (or even if it is already installed, it is still better to run it off a device other than the one you are attempting to recover data from in case it tries to write configuration files, etc).
4. Ensure that the data recovery software you are using (whether its PhotoRec, GetDataBack, Restoration or any other) is not saving the recovered files back onto the device from which you want to recover the data until you are absolutely sure that you will not want to perform any further data recovery from that device.